# proof that $f'$ is continuous at $a$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ derivable in set I.
 if $\lim x_n = \lim y_n =a \in I$ with $x_n \neq y_n$ and $\lim \frac{f(y_n)-f(x_n)}{y_n - x_n} = f'(a)$ 
proof that $f'$ is continuous at $a$

my attempt
$x_n \neq y_n$ so by MVT $\exists z_n \in I$ like $x_n \geq z_n \geq y_n$ with $\frac{f(y_n)-f(x_n)}{y_n - x_n}=f'(z_n)$ for each $x_n$ and  $y_n$
then $f'(a) = \lim\frac{f(y_n)-f(x_n)}{y_n - x_n}= \lim f'(z_n)$

Using $\lim x_n = \lim y_n = a$ and $x_n \geq z_n \geq y_n \Rightarrow z_n \rightarrow a$ 
if $ \lim_{x\rightarrow a} f'(x) \neq f'(a)$ then $\exists \epsilon > 0$ such $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$, $z_n \in [x_n,y_n]$ $0 < |z_n - a| < \frac{1}{n}$ and $|f'(z_n) - f'(a)| \geq \epsilon$. So $z_n \rightarrow a$ but will do not have $\lim f'(z_n) = f'(a)$

so $\lim f'(z_n) = f'(a) = \lim_{x\rightarrow a} f'(x)$ when $z_n \rightarrow a$

 and thats implies $f'$ continuous at $a$

my question is, that's correct ? if not, can you help me? thanks

Comment: The claim is not clear, I guess. Does it hold for all sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$ or just for some?

Comment: thank you @HagenvonEitzen for your reply. Is for any $x_n$ and $y_n$, only need that $x_n \neq y_n$ and $\rightarrow a$

Comment: Anyway, your proof is not watertight: You should show that $f'(z_n)\to f'(a)$ for *all* sequences $z_n\to a$. The sequence $z_n$ will be different for different sequences $x_n,y_n$, but is ultimatly beyond your control, i.e. not arbitrary.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen thanks for your reply. Thats why i post the question ... i was not shure about the $z_n$. Do you see a way too fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f'$ was not continous at $a$, there would be points $a_1,a_2,\ldots$ such that $a_n\rightarrow a$ for which $|f'(a_n)-f'(a)|>\varepsilon$. Then, there would be a point $x_i$ arbitrarily close to $a_i$ such that $\left|\frac{f(x_i)-f(a_i)}{x_i-a_i}-f'(a)\right|>\varepsilon/2$, and we get a contradiction because both $a_n$ and $x_n$ tend to $a$ as $n$ gets large.

Comment: thank you for your anwser, but for me is not clear where you used $f'(a) = \lim\frac{f(y_n)-f(x_n)}{y_n - x_n}$ can you be more rigorous in its demonstration.. Thanks again.

Comment: @Francisco I used this to get a contradiction. In fact, the inequality $\left|\frac{f(x_i)-f(a_i)}{x_i-a_i}-f'(a)\right|>\varepsilon/2$, proven in my answer, means that $\lim\frac{f(x_i)-f(a_i)}{x_i-a_i}$ is not $f'(a)$.